# i can't understand this class component (react)

Tags: reactjs

I can't understand this class component (react)
that's my first time work on e-commerce site with react.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {storeProducts, detailProduct} from '../data'; 
const ProductContext = React.createContext(); //to pass data by createcontext//

class ProductProvider extends Component {
    state={
        products : [],
        detailProduct : detailProduct
      
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setProducts();
    }
    setProducts =()=>{
        let tempProducts = [];
        storeProducts.forEach(item =>{
            const singleItem = {...item};
            tempProducts = [...tempProducts,singleItem];
        });
        this.setState(()=>{
            return { products: tempProducts};
        });
    };
```

Comment: You need to learn Javascript and then React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is invoked immediately after the ProductProvider component is mounted. And once it is called it will trigger `setProducts` function.
The `setProducts` function is going over each product from `storeProducts` and adds them to an array of updated products, the state of `products` will be changed with this array of products and that will trigger the `render` function that will render the UI with the updated `products` list.
according to the code that you shared, `detailProduct` has no impact on the functionality.

Comment: thank you  Shimi i understand a lot , but why we use componentDidMount are we if not use this lifecycle the setProducts not work ?

Comment: I'll need to see the full code to answer this question, but it is common to use `componentDidMount()` when the data needs to be initialized, and in your case, it will initialize the `products` list before rendering the UI, which I think maybe an important aspect for your app.

Comment: I understand you mean it is useful to use componentDidMount if i have a data and i need this data print in UI

Answer (score 0):

could you please elaborate on what you are not understanding in the react class component, from your code I could only tell that it has a missing render function. render function is one of the important and mandatory functions in reactjs call component.

Please check with w3school.
https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_components.asp

Comment: i cant ubderstand why he didn't type in state {products : storeProducts}

Comment: Well not sure what is in storeProducts, either array of array or object of array I think that's why you first restructure it and then set it as a state.